# Error in the route when I'm not in developer mode Symfony 2.8

Tags: ajax, symfony, yaml

I have an error in `routing.yml` according to the browser console, that problem is that this error only appears when the URL to which I am working is not in developer mode.

URL `something.cd/admin` to URL developer `something.cd/app_dev.php/admin`

This error is the next when i am not developer mode

```
router.js:9 Uncaught Error: The route "get_icon_metadatacap_edit" does not exist.
at K.f.i (router.js:9)
at K.f.m (router.js:10)
at getInfoMetadataporcapa (bundle.js:28438)
at Object.ID_1 (bundle.js:28705)
at Dispatcher._invokeCallback (bundle.js:26342)
at Dispatcher.dispatch (bundle.js:26318)
at Dispatcher.handleServerAction (bundle.js:25898)
at Object.cargarInfoMetadata (bundle.js:25631)
at Object.actualizarMetadata (bundle.js:65947)
at HTMLUnknownElement.boundFunc (bundle.js:6975)
```

I have the next code in the ruting.yml

```
get_icon_metadatacap_edit:
  path:     /geticonmetadataedit
  defaults: { _controller: AdministradorBundle:Capa:getIconsMetadataEdit }
  options:
    expose: true
```

I use routing in the `ajax` code

```
url:Routing.generate("get_icon_metadatacap_edit"),
```

I think it's a `Error 500` permissions error but I do not know where I can visualize that error and where I have to get in order to solve it

Comment: 500 is not permission error. It is unexpected internal server error.

Comment: Can you please show the full error and it's stack trace? You should find more information in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve the error by clearing the cache for it I put the following commandsin my virtaul machine, `Centos 6.4` in `PHP 5.6.38`

```
 php app/console assetic:dump
 php app/console cache:clear --env=dev
 php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug
 chmod -R 777 app/cache/
 chmod -R 777 app/logs/
 chmod -R 777 var/cache/
 chmod -R 777 var/sessions/
 php app/console assets:install --symlink
```

I realized that because when I was looking at the code that should be compiled, it was not all updated.